# How do I extract value from object {System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, object>?

Tags: c#, object

I have the following object:

`object {System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, object>}`

Key is "ipAddresses" string 
Value is `object[]` where [0] in this array is an object[string] 
that I would like to extract. (it's an IP address)

I tried the following code among other things with no success:

```
object.GetType().Getproperty("ipAddresses")
object.GetType().GetField("ipAddresses")
```

Note that the object type is: (from watch)

value

{[ipAddresses,System.Object[]]}

Type

object{System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair}

I'd like to save `value[0]` from the KeyValuePair to a string. Any help would be highly appreciated :)

Comment: Since when does `System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair` have a property called `ipAddresses`? Your code has a very specific intent which simply makes no sense.

Comment: well i think you could do object.Value[0][0] or Am I Wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
object obj; //get key value pair from somewhere
object ips = ((KeyValuePair<string, object>)obj).Value;
string ip = ((object[])ips)[0].ToString();
```

Comment: I tried and got the following exception:

'((KeyValuePair<string, object[]>)value).Value' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException'
    Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
    HResult: -2147467262
    HelpLink: null
    InnerException: null
    Message: "Specified cast is not valid."
    Source: null
    StackTrace: null
    TargetSite: null
 
 
Note that the type is (from watch)

Name     value                                Type

obj      {[ipAddresses,System.Object[]]}      object{System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,object>}

Comment: Wow stack overflow really doesnt want me to add spaces or new lines... I hope you can understand whats written there :)

Comment: Did you mean object ips = ((KeyValuePair<string, object>)obj).Value ? as casting to object[] ips wont complie... I tried without and got "Specified cast is not valid." exception. Look at my updated original question, I've added the specific types from watch. Thank you very much for the effort!

Comment: @ItamarLevy Did you get the exception on the same line? You had exception on line `2` earlier but now it could be on line `3`.

Comment: It's working! I probably didn't copy it properly. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

```
string ipAddress = object["ipAddresses"][0];
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, I get the following error when I try this option: "error CS0021: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'"